# CGImageDestinationFinalize or UIImageJPEGRepresentation - Crash when saving a large file on IOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, core-image

I am trying to create tiles for a larger image, and it seems that as of IOS 10 the following code no longer works and crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

This happens on IOS 10 Device only, IOS 9 works fine.

The crash happens with any image that is larger than ~1300x1300.

Profiling in instruments doesn't yield anything interesting and points to CGImageDestinationFinalize.

There is no memory spike.

I tried both ways below:

```
UIImage* tempImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tileImage];
NSData*  imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 0.8f); // CRASH HERE.
```

OR

```
+ (BOOL) CGImageWriteToFile: (CGImageRef) image andPath: (NSString *)path
{
    CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);
    if (!destination) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create CGImageDestination for %@", path);
        return NO;
    }

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, nil);

    if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) { // CRASH HERE
        NSLog(@"Failed to write image to %@", path);
        CFRelease(destination);
        return NO;
    }

    CFRelease(destination);
```

As I understand it UIImageJPEGRepresentation in turn calls CGImageDestinationFinalize eventually.

Edit: Forgot to mention the images are written to hdd, but about half way through.

This really does seem like something to do with IOS 10, could this be a bug?

I also filed the bug with apple just in case.

Any help or workarounds on how to write out large images is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Could this be a bug?* If you're ever asking that, [just file one](http://bugreport.apple.com). Ask SO, too, if you're looking for extra confirmation/help/workarounds, but do file a bug regardless.

Comment: Bug filed. Any help with workarounds is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question here.

What I have gathered is that IOS 10 has trouble saving a file that has color mode "**grayscale**".

So if you do

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 0.8f)
```

and if tempImage is **grayscale** you will get a crash.

I was processing many images and it didn't click until later that it could be related to the color mode of the image.

I already filed a bug with apple to see what they say, but meanwhile I had to find a temporary fix.

My fix was to convert image to RGB by drawing it and capturing it into a new image.

Sample method:

```
+ (UIImage *)convertImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sourceImage.size);
    [sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, sourceImage.size.width, sourceImage.size.height)];

    UIImage *targetImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return targetImage;
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: It does not help on my test picture.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ffMzwWl7Zik9u7_SYaBqeWEO_ibH-PiS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

1. `tempimage` is one of the parameters you passed to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`; if it points to a dead object, then that will cause a crash when `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` tries to use that dead object. check whether `tempImage` is nil.
2. check whether you are adding image after calling `CGImageDestinationFinalize`  at destination

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
tempimage is not null. As I mentioned in the question, it only happens if that image IS larger than 1400x1400. And resulting image IS written to HDD, but half way.  :(