# UIImageJPEGRepresentation - Crash IOS 10 : -[NSConcreteMutableData CGImage]: unrecognized selector issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10

I'm converting image to `NSData`. For previous `iOS` version, it was ok. But now its **crashing in iOS 10.0**.

**I think crash here:**

```
UIImage * image=[selectedPhotos objectAtIndex:i];
NSData *imageData =[[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 1.0)];
```

Someone, suggest me to do this: [CGImageDestinationFinalize or UIImageJPEGRepresentation - Crash when saving a large file on IOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710875/cgimagedestinationfinalize-or-uiimagejpegrepresentation-crash-when-saving-a-la)

**I called it like:**

```
UIImage * image=[self convertImage:[selectedPhotos objectAtIndex:i]]; //Dont worry, i am getting the image from array
imageData=[[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 1.0)];
```

**And the method :**

```
-(UIImage *)convertImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sourceImage.size);
    [sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, sourceImage.size.width, sourceImage.size.height)];

    UIImage *targetImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return targetImage;
 }
```

Still it shows the issue :

> -[NSConcreteMutableData CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000005dfd0

Still its crashing. Any solution ?

Comment: Long-story-short: you think that object is an image, but it's data.  How is the data acquired?

Comment: use breakpoints to specify.

Comment: No, its same on that line where i applied conversion image to nsdata.@vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `[selectedPhotos objectAtIndex:i]` is not returning a `UIImage`.